# Creating a pivot table with subtotals and getting percentage of parent total in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am able to create a pivot table in python pandas, however am unable to get subtotals. I get the grand column total and row total but not sub totals in between.

Ex:If the pivot I created in Python is as follows, I would like to get the subtotal of BU:A and Region:APAC. Similarly the subtotal of BU:A and Region:EU and so on. Please help.

Table:

```
BU  Region   Level  Jan      Feb      Mar
A    APAC     1     value    value    value
              2     value    value    value
              3     value    value    value
     EU       1     value    value    value
              2     value    value    value
              3     value    value    value
     NA       1     value    value    value
              2     value    value    value
              3     value    value    value
B    APAC     1     value    value    value
              2     value    value    value
              3     value    value    value
     EU       1     value    value    value
              2     value    value    value
              3     value    value    value
     NA       1     value    value    value
              2     value    value    value
              3     value    value    value
```

Answer (score 1):

Use groupby and pd.concat than pivot table i.e

```
x = df.groupby(level=['BU','Region']).apply(sum).assign(Level='Total')
# if BU and Region is not index then use df.groupby(['BU,'Region'])...
# if the values are numbers then `.sum()` than `.apply(sum)`
ndf = pd.concat([df,x]).sort_index()
```

Output :

```
          Level              Jan              Feb              Mar
BU Region

A  APAC        1            value            value            value
   APAC        2            value            value            value
   APAC        3            value            value            value
   APAC    Total  valuevaluevalue  valuevaluevalue  valuevaluevalue
   EU          1            value            value            value
   EU          2            value            value            value
   EU          3            value            value            value
   EU      Total  valuevaluevalue  valuevaluevalue  valuevaluevalue
   NaN         1            value            value            value
   NaN         2            value            value            value
   NaN         3            value            value            value
B  APAC        1            value            value            value
   APAC        2            value            value            value
   APAC        3            value            value            value
   APAC    Total  valuevaluevalue  valuevaluevalue  valuevaluevalue
   EU          1            value            value            value
   EU          2            value            value            value
   EU          3            value            value            value
   EU      Total  valuevaluevalue  valuevaluevalue  valuevaluevalue
   NaN         1            value            value            value
   NaN         2            value            value            value
   NaN         3            value            value            value
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael I was using apply for different function then changed it to sum :)

Comment: And It just gives nan since they are strings. So I keep apply here.